# Is this a good python design?

Tags: python, django, decorator

I'm using django and i wrote this decorator to take away some of the repetitive code i found for ajax views and i want to know your opinion (too basic, bad design, try this instead, ok, etc).

```
def ajax_only(func):
    def _ajax_only(request,*args,**kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponse('<p>Ajax not supported.</p>')
        else:
            return func(request,*args,**kwargs)
    return _ajax_only
```

Comment: This is a better question for http://s.tk/review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a typical and effective use of a decorator.

Answer (score 5):

The only other tip I'd have here is to suggest the use of the `functools.wraps` decorator - it allows the decorated function to keep some attributes (such as function name), which makes it easier for debugging - the code above would be like:

```
from functools import wraps
def ajax_only(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _ajax_only(request,*args,**kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponse('<p>Ajax not supported.</p>')
        else:
            return func(request,*args,**kwargs)
    return _ajax_only
```

Comment: thanks, i heard about that decorator in a google tech talk video, but they just mentioned and i was wondering where i could find it.